# Определение страницы внутри фрейма

Tags: html, php

Всем привет.

Можно ли каким-либо методом определить, открыта страница внутри фрейма (iframe) или нет? Скажем:

```
<?
// определяем открыта ли страница внутри фрейма или нет, выдаем $frame = yes|no;
if($frame==yes)
{
    echo "содержимое страницы";
}
esle
{
    echo "ошибка страницы";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (self.parent.frames.length != 0) {
    self.parent.location = document.location;
}
```

Решение для JS. PHP все равно где открыта страница.

Comment: а если у пользователя отключен JS ?

Comment: тогда "ой". :)
Дело в том, что если пользователь - злобный буратино, то тут почти никогда нельзя ничего сделать: всегда найдется противодейстие.
Так что встает вопрос: зачем вам защищать от открытия в Iframe? Если для защиты контента - забудте, все равно сопрут. А если для педотвращения открытия сайта в собственном Iframe - меняйте логику меню.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (self.parent !== self) 
{
    alert('frame');
}
```